# Which online course for beginners can be completed in the smallest number of hours?

Tags: learning, course

I'm looking for a course where the projected time to read through the text and work through the exercises has been estimated. Ideally it should cover the basics for beginners from A1 to B2.

Comment: I do not think that this post is too broad because 1) it asks for courses where the expected completion time has been estimated, and not for us to decide what we think the time will be, and 2) it specifies the level the course is designed for and the level the course is designed to bring its user to.

Comment: In what language(s)? Duolingo for example is available only in English, and possibly Spanish very soon. So even if it would be fast, it would work only for people that speak English (or Spanish).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best approach is to use [*Zagreba Metodo*](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zagreba_metodo). It is a course which is especially created for teaching of 500 basic words.

[Here](http://learn.esperanto.com) is the best course which uses *Zagreba Metodo*.

Answer (score 5):

My students use "Kurso de Esperanto" created by Karlo Pereira from Brazil. Most of them complete all the lessons in less than 20 hours.

La Zagreba Metodo should be faster. It teaches about 500 word-roots, which should be enough to get some fluency. 
It has sound. You can listen while you read.

A book scanned:  (with sound)
http://esperantofre.com/zagreb/zagreba.htm
It has links to the corresponding interactive lessons.

Interactive. Touch a word to find its meaning:  (with sound)
http://learn.esperanto.com/en/

Answer (score 3):

I found **ikurso** 10 lessons enough straightforward and give a pretty good foundations of the language in minimum amount of time:

- http://www.kurso.com.br/ (English version)
- http://ikurso.esperanto-france.org/ (French version)

Answer (score 1):

I used the approach with Duolingo and Lernu to do a lesson or course everyday, in that way i used like 20 minutes for day but like at school I didn't forgot what I learned.
Do a little bit every day is helpful to remember because everyday you use the words. I tried with Kurso4 but was to most fast.